# Fedora 28 is not starting: "acpi MST0101:00: platform device creation failed"

Tags: fedora

I have never experienced issues with my fedora 28 in my laptop, until recently, after not using my laptop for two-three weeks.
Now every time I start the laptop, I received the following error when the OS is loading:

```
failed to claim resource 1: [nen0xfed40000-oxfed40ff]
[ 0.123896] acpi MST0101:00: platform device creation failed: 
-16
generating /run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt
```

Note that It stops in a very limited terminal session. Hence, I cannot find the way to mount a usb key to copy the above mentioned file (my lack of experience).

I started the system using a borrowed usb key with Ubuntu, and have no problems at all, so I discard any hardware issue.

Still, the above mentioned file does not exists, or perhaps is removed when I started using the usb key?

Anyway, if you can help me or refer me to any source to fix the problem, and be able to use my Fedora again I will really appreciate it.

I do not want to install the OS again, and lose my installed programs and configuration.